# CloverETL mySQL Database SSL secure connection & Parameters

Tags: mysql, ssl, parameters, connection

I am trying to make the connection to a remote mysql database in CloverETL Designer (Community Version)

Documentation with examples on this subject seem fragmented so I have tried to piece the bits together but I'm not use if they are correct. I would be grateful for any suggestions or further clarification on this subject.

Here is what I have so far:

**The SSL Certificate**

As an alternative VPN connection the server guys passed me the raw CA certificate, which I saved as a .crt file in the conn folder of the CloverETL workspace.

**CloverETL Connections**

- I created a new DB connection and tested it was working without SSL
- In the graph window I created a simple graph
- Switching to Source View I added the parameter attribute to the connection code like this:

  `<Connection database="MYSQL" dbURL="jdbc:mysql://hostname/database_name" id="JDBC0" jdbcSpecific="MYSQL" name="CPM" parameters="ssl=${WORKSPACE}/conn/mysql_cpm_cert.crt" password="password" type="JDBC" user="username"/>`
- Then I tested the connection to the database by creating new metadata from a DB table

**The problem is that I don't know if the connect is now secure or not.**

Here's the list of resources that I used to piece together the information:

[components:bulkloaders:mysql_data_writer    [CloverETL wiki]](http://wiki.cloveretl.com/doku.php?id=components%3abulkloaders%3amysql_data_writer#load_parameters)

[MySQL ::   MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 6.3.6.3 SSL Command Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl-cert)

Thanks
CPM

Answer (score 0):

Your setup almost certainly does not use ssl. Both links you posted are not usable - first describes bulk loader and second connection via command line client. But what you need is to configure JDBC. So I would use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html section "Security."

I would set:

- useSSL=true
- requireSSL=true

You will do that by adding items in table (Custom JDBC properties) on second tab (Advanced) of Connection Wizard. In source it should appear like "jdbc.useSSL=true jdbc.requireSSL=true" not "parameters=".

Then connection should fail, because in your default java key store is missing your certificate. It can be imported via http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html section "Importing Certificates"

I hope this helps.